# Seeing unexpected synchronous behavior using subprocess.Popen under git bash

Tags: python, windows, bash

I don't have access to Windows, but I wrote some test code for a co-worker to run, and it demonstrated that `subprocess.Popen` was behaving synchronously under `git bash`, asynchronously under Windows CMD.

The child process sleeps for 5 seconds before terminating, yet the code following `subprocess.Popen` in the parent does not execute under `git bash` until after the child exits. This was true using both Python 3.7 and 3.10.

I can't find any documentation to indicate that this is expected behavior, and it certainly doesn't behave that way under macOS or Linux.

### Parent

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import subprocess, time, sys
proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'child.py'])
print(f'Parent: launched child process {proc.pid}.')
time.sleep(10)
print('Parent: Done sleeping, terminating.')
sys.exit(0)
```

### Child

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import time, sys
print("Child: I'm going to sleep for 5 seconds.")
time.sleep(5)
print("Child: I'm awake again. Exiting.")
sys.exit(-1)
```

### CMD

```
Parent: launched child process 12244.
Child: I'm going to sleep for 5 seconds.
Child: I'm awake again. Exiting.
Parent: Done sleeping, terminating.
```

### Git bash

```
Child: I'm going to sleep for 5 seconds.
Child: I'm awake again. Exiting.
Parent: launched child process 85372.
Parent: Done sleeping, terminating.
```

Comment: Are you using the same python in both cases?

Comment: Yes, the code I posted is the same run in both shells.

Comment: Unfortunately I'll have to wait for Monday to ask my co-worker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a print buffering issue, you can run the parent with:

```
python -u parent.py
```

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't considered that. I'm skeptical: the reason I wrote this simple test code was I was seeing bad behavior in a more complex setup, but it's absolutely worth testing. (Plus I didn't know about `-u`!)

Comment: There are some other bad behaviors with git bash & python that made this harder to troubleshoot (`winpty python` seems to address those), but you were right: simply addressing the buffering got the test scripts to display properly.

Comment: Try `Windows Terminal` which is better than git-bash terminal ot mintty (I think)...